# with is not woking in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

The redirect url is working well but the message is not showing.It looks with method is not working.

**Controller**

```
return redirect('/Patient_Home')->with(['payment_success','Payment has been completed successfully']);
```

**view**

```
    @if(Session::has('payment_success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="text-align:center">
             {{Session::get('payment_success')}}
        </div>  

@endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```php
return redirect()->route('your patient home route')->with('payment_success','Payment has been completed successfully');
```

On blade view, try this:

```php
@if ($message = Session::get('payment_success'))
    {{ $message }}
@endif
```

Also, run this command to clear caches:
`php artisan optimize:clear`

Regards

Comment: What doesn't work? The redirect should work IF you placed the proper route name.

Comment: sir redirect is working properly but the message i want to display is not showing there.here is route that i defined **Route::get('/appointment','Patient_Controller@chk_doc')->name('patient home');**

Comment: So, if the redirect is OK, check the updated answer to handle the message.

Comment: same issue. i cant understand whats wrong with this.Too many headache.

Comment: run this command in inside the project folder: ```php artisan optimize:clear```. And test again.

Comment: Thank you sir. You helped me a lot till i succeed. Optimization command worked for me.

Comment: Ok, nice to know! Mark the post as answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have created a RedirectResponse instance to flash data to the session in a single method chain. This is also works for storing status messages after an action:

```
return redirect('/Patient_Home')->with(['payment_success','Payment has been completed successfully']);

@if (session('payment_success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('payment_success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you sir but i use optimize command and it solved my problem.